# Using WebRTC for Video Streaming in android app

Tags: android, webrtc, turn, webrtc-android

I am using WebRTC for communication for media streaming between my android app and web app.
For signalling I have used socket.io and using socket I have established the connection between android app and web app. I am able to send offer and receive answer on Mobile app and ideally after that the streaming should start but in my case it is throwing this error on the web.

```
 WebRTC: ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details
 failed screen.js:835:25
 Need to reconnect student screen.js:838:33
 Ice Connecttion state Changed to disconnected|closed|failed
```

I think this is happening because connection can't be established with the TURN server.
Can someone help me with this. I am using this piece of code for TURN server connection.
Also please tell me how can i verify if my connection with TURN has been established.

```
 try {



        PeerConnection.IceServer peerIceServer1=PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.XXXXXX.com:3478")
                .setUsername("XXXXXX")
                .setPassword("XXXXXX")
                .setTlsCertPolicy(PeerConnection.TlsCertPolicy.TLS_CERT_POLICY_INSECURE_NO_CHECK)
                .createIceServer();

        String username1 = "XXXXX";
        String credential1 = "XXXXXX/XXXXXXXX=";
        String turnUrll = "turn:turn.XXXX.com:3478";

 
        PeerConnection.IceServer peerIceServer = PeerConnection.IceServer.builder(turnUrll)
                .setUsername(username1)
                .setPassword(credential1)
                .setTlsCertPolicy(PeerConnection.TlsCertPolicy.TLS_CERT_POLICY_INSECURE_NO_CHECK)
                .createIceServer();

        peerIceServers.add(peerIceServer);
        peerIceServers.add(peerIceServer1);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the piece of code where i am trying to create peer connection.

```
  private void createPeerConnection() {

    PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(peerIceServers);
    // TCP candidates are only useful when connecting to a server that supports
    // ICE-TCP.
    rtcConfig.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.ENABLED;
    rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE;
    rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE;
    rtcConfig.continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY;
    // Use ECDSA encryption.
    rtcConfig.keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA;
    localPeer = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig,
            new CustomPeerConnectionObserver("localPeerCreation") {
                @Override
                public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                    super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
                    onIceCandidateReceived(iceCandidate);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                    showToast("Received Remote stream");
                    super.onAddStream(mediaStream);
                }
            });


    addStreamToLocalPeer();
}
```

If anyone wants to have more better view of code i will share more details. please i need help since i can't even find the documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that the turn server you are using is not active anymore.
Please note: it is almost impossible to find free TURN server. as far as i know, there is only one free turn server which is working and it is:http://numb.viagenie.ca .
Please note: this turn server is working but it is not good enough and you are get disconnected very often.
you should user is as follow:

`private ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServer = new ArrayList<>(); iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer()); iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:numb.viagenie.ca").createIceServer()); iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("turn:numb.viagenie.ca").setUsername("YOUR_USER_NAME").setPassword("YOUR_PASSWORD").createIceServer());`

and pass it to the PeerConnection.

Alternatively, you can create a development account on XIRSYS and get free monthly quote and use it.

Comment: I have been able to resolve it.The problem was with SDP. I will post the code and a tutorial on the same very soon that can be helpful to many people out there.

Comment: when is 'soon' ?

Comment: @VipinNU Can we also use this for implement screen share to remote web app from android device?

Comment: Yes. can be done. @PrasanthRavi

Comment: @VipinNU Can you please help on some tutorial or reference links to implement this ?